# ::write() and ::read() has not been declared error. Qt5 UNIX signal handling

Tags: c++, linux, unix, signals, qt5

So, I'm trying to follow the tutorial given

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/unix-signals.html

to catch UNIX/Linux signals and do something Qt related when triggered by them.

It's on the qtDocs, so I consider it legit.

My present code is as follows:

mydaemon.cpp

```
#include "mydaemon.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>
#include <QSocketNotifier>
#include <csignal>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>


//needed to not get an undefined reference to static members
int MyDaemon::sighupFd[2];
int MyDaemon::sigtermFd[2];

MyDaemon::MyDaemon(QObject *parent)
: QObject(parent)
{
if (::socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, sighupFd))
    qFatal("Couldn't create HUP socketpair");

if (::socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, sigtermFd))
    qFatal("Couldn't create TERM socketpair");

snHup = new QSocketNotifier(sighupFd[1], QSocketNotifier::Read, this);
connect(snHup, SIGNAL(activated(int)), this, SLOT(handleSigHup()));
snTerm = new QSocketNotifier(sigtermFd[1], QSocketNotifier::Read, this);
connect(snTerm, SIGNAL(activated(int)), this, SLOT(handleSigTerm()));
}

MyDaemon::~MyDaemon() {}

void MyDaemon::hupSignalHandler(int)
{
 qDebug() << "signal hup";
  char a = '1';

::write(sighupFd[0], &a, sizeof(a));
}

void MyDaemon::termSignalHandler(int)
{
qDebug() << "signal term";
char a = '1';
::write(sigtermFd[0], &a, sizeof(a));
}

void MyDaemon::handleSigTerm()
{
snTerm->setEnabled(false);
char tmp;
::read(sigtermFd[1], &tmp, sizeof(tmp));

// do Qt stuff
qDebug() << "MyDaemon::handleSigTerm";

snTerm->setEnabled(true);
}

void MyDaemon::handleSigHup()
{
snHup->setEnabled(false);
char tmp;
::read(sighupFd[1], &tmp, sizeof(tmp));

// do Qt stuff
qDebug() << "MyDaemon::handleSigHup";

snHup->setEnabled(true);
}
```

Now, when I create my C++ class, and try to build, it gives the errors such as,

/home/xxxx/Documents/Qt Projects/mainScreen/mydaemon.cpp:-1: In static member function 'static void MyDaemon::termSignalHandler(int)':
/home/xxxx/Documents/Qt Projects/mainScreen/mydaemon.cpp:49: error: '::write' has not been declared
     ::write(sigtermFd[0], &a, sizeof(a));
     ^

and so on, for all instances of the ::read() or ::write() calls. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I'm grateful for any help :)

Comment: I guess you need `#include <unistd.h>`...

Comment: Wow, that was a mundane mistake. It worked :D Thanks a ton. It's a shame that qtCreator doesn't have a ctrl+shift+o type of functionality.

Comment: First, you're not allowed to use `qDebug` in signal handler. You don't know what it does. If it triggers a `malloc` or similar you're in UB land. Second, under Linux you can also think of using a `signalfd` instead of installing signal handlers.

Comment: Right now I've used qDebug only for testing to make sure it reaches that section. I intend to do other things. But yes, I will look into signalfd. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using "basic" Unix functions, you need to use

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

This will give you `read`, `write`, `open`, `close`, `sleep`, `usleep` and many other functions.